# VBA, for loop with a nested do while loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set where each row has an abbreviation then a date associated with it.  Then the next row is the same abbreviation with the next date.  At the end of the date "range", it changes to the next abbreviation, running through another date range.

I want to loop through the entire dataset of course, but then I want to have an inner loop for the subset of each abbreviation.  My thought was to increment the outer loop within the inner loop, so that when the inner one finishes, the outer one skips to the next set of abbreviations, but I don't think the outer For loop will allow me to do this.

The code looks like this.  Is there a way to have the For loop not iterate through each value but instead to "jump ahead" to the last value of this Do loop?

```
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
'Create a loop through the abbreviations
        Do While Cells(i, 1).value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).value
        i = i + 1
        Loop
        
        
    Next i
```

Comment: When using a `For...Next` loop it's considered bad practice to alter the loop counter within the loop.  If you need to do something like that then a `Do` loop is a better option.

Comment: I see you've edited the title to focus on `Do` instead of `For` loops.  But you already have an answer that broadly explains how to do that.  If you need more help it would be best to edit your question to include some sample data, the expected output (both as text), the code you've currently got using Do loops, what output you currently get, and any errors you get.

Comment: ok sounds good.  i'm trying to get back in stack overflows good graces and only changed the title.  i'm a complete newbie and am stumbling around like crazy. thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply use two `Do While` loops and increment `i` when your condition is not true:

```vb
    i = 2

    Do While i <= LastRow
    
        'Create a loop through the abbreviations
        If Cells(i, 1).value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).value Then
           Do While Cells(i, 1).value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).value
              i = i + 1
           Loop
        Else
           i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why I need the IF statement here.  Can you explain what happens if we simply leave it out and have 2 DO loops?

Comment: If you leave out the `If` statement, then anytime the code does not execute the inner `Do While` loop, it consequently does not execute `i = i + 1` in that iteration, so the value of `i` stays the same and the program gets stuck in an infinite loop.

The `If` statement therefore makes the code behave like a `For` loop, but with the added benefit of conditionally being able to jump forward where applicable.

Another approach is to use a Boolean to detect if the inner loop is entered into, and increment `i` if not.

Comment: I'm realizing I can simply put the i = i + 1 outside the loop and it will work the same without the IF.  Thanks so much for your help.  Really needed to be thinking of it as 2 DO loops rather than figuring out a FOR

Comment: You can do that with no problem provided it makes sense when the inner loop is called, as there will be one extra increment to `i` in that case. Just test it out and adapt it as works best for you :)